# Plotting the following function

Tags: plotting, export

I have to plot the following function and I also need to export it somehow, as an image or another kind of file (I need to use it in $\LaTeX$ after),

Here is the function:

\begin{equation}
y(t)=656.96-156.96e^{0.25t}+39.24t
\end{equation}
I know how to plot simple functions in *Mathematica*: `Plot[ f, {x , xmin, xmax}]` and then shift+enter.

However I have been trying to plot the function above and it doesn't work. What I obtain is clearly a wrong graph. I've realised maybe my problem could be how to write the exponential inside that expression.
Could someone please tell me the command the plot this function? `y(t)` should be on the ordinates and $t$ in the abscissa.

This is the code that I have used in `Mathematica`:

```
Plot[656.96 - 156.96*Exp[0.25*t] + 39.24*t, {t, -500, 500}]
```

Comment: Include the code you tried in your question. Someone will be able to see what you have done and point you in the correct direction.

Comment: The exponential function in Mathematica is either represented as `E^(0.25 t)` (note the capital `E`), or as `Exp[0.25 t]`. A lowercase `e` would not work. Also, have you substituted `t` for `x` in your plot range?

Comment: I've just edited my question Edmund, thank you!
And yeah I used t, in my plot range, you can see my code above now.

Comment: That seems to be correct syntax. What is wrong with the output you get? In other words, what were you expecting instead?

Comment: I was expecting a graph with two roots, namely: $t=7.14881$ and $t=-16.6803$.
Furthermore the graph should have a negative side with positive slope and then, after intersecting the y-axis in $y=500$, should have a negative slope.

Comment: Think about the magnitude of these numbers: `Exp[0.25*500]` and `Exp[-0.25*500]`.  One is huge, the other is almost zero.  What do you expect to see on the plot?  I don't think [-500, 500] is a sensible range for such an exponential.

Comment: What do you think would be a sensible range, then?
Thank you for your observation Szabolcs

Comment: Furthermore I would like to know how I can export the graph. I would like to use it in $Latex$ later

Comment: Well, think about it for a moment, don't just put in random numbers as the range.  The difference of your roots is ~23, that's 0.02 times the width of your range.  Mathematica's default images size is 360 pixels, so your roots would be a barely visible 7 pixels apart.  Thin about what values you expect from your equation and choose a reasonable range based on that, e.g. just around your roots.  Also play with `PlotRange` to show an interesting vertical range, not everything dow to $-10^{56}$, which is the value of your function at 500.

Comment: Have you searched the documentation for "export"?  Have you searched it for the format you want to use in LaTeX?  (EPS?  PDF?)

Comment: I need to export is as PNG, I've just found how to do it thanks.  And you were right, it was a problem with the range.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
y[t_] = 656.96 - 156.96 E^(0.25 t) + 39.24 t // Rationalize

(*  16424/25 - (3924*E^(t/4))/25 + 
   (981*t)/25  *)
```

The zeroes are

```
Solve[y[x] == 0, x, Reals] // N

(*  {{x -> -16.6803}, {x -> 7.14882}}  *)
```

The maximum value is

```
max = Maximize[y[x], x, Reals][[1]]

(*  500  *)
```

Absent some other criteria, set the plot domain such that the plot range is `{-max, max}`

```
{xmin, xmax} = x /. Solve[y[x] == -max, x, Reals] // N

(*  {-29.4817, 9.06228}  *)

Plot[y[t], {t, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[`WolframAlpha`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) is a reasonably good tool for beginners to explore how to figure out code on such a problem as this.

Just paste your formula into a string for `WolframAlpha` and it will try to figure out a reasonable way to graph it.

```
WolframAlpha["656.96-156.96*Exp[0.25*t]+39.24*t"]
```

[image]

There are `min` and `max` sliders that allow dynamic adjustment of the plot domain.  Clicking the `+` button in the upper right corner of the pod and selecting "Input" yields the following code:

```
{HoldComplete[Plot[656.96 - 156.96 E^(0.25 t) + 39.24 t, {t, -12, 12}]], 
 HoldComplete[Plot[656.96 - 156.96 E^(0.25 t) + 39.24 t, {t, -72, 72}]]}
```

One can copy the `Plot` command from inside `HoldComplete` and perhaps change `-12` to something like `-30` that would include the other root.  The output that is not shown also includes the roots of the function and its maximum, among other things.